# Android multi-level menu

Tags: android

I am looking for resources (preferably a tutorial, otherwise a downloadable example) on creating multi-level listviews, similar to the settings menu on phones (e.g. Keyboard > Languages > English) or file browsers, where each selection on the list can open a new level of list, with back button implemented and other needed navigational candy. I seem to be having trouble searching for it. I keep getting results about hierarchy viewer.

Comment: Asking for off-site resources is considered off-topic for Stack Overflow nowadays (see item #5 on https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @CommonsWare Sorry. Then can I ask for instructions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then can I ask for instructions?

The classic approach is fairly simple:

- Use a `ListActivity` for each level in the hierarchy
- In `onListItemClick()` of a non-leaf level, call `startActivity()` to launch the activity to show the next level, passing in details of what to show via `Intent` extras as needed
- In `onListItemClick()` of leaf levels, call `startActivity()` to launch something to implement whatever the "menu" represents

In the literal case of an app like Settings, you should be using a `PreferenceActivity` -- it is unclear to me if you are using this to actually collect settings, though.

You could also use one activity with multiple `ListFragment` implementations for each level, using a `FragmentTransaction` to replace the fragments as the user drills down into the "menu". Use `addToBackStack()` in the `FragmentTransaction` to automate handling the BACK button.

However, to be honest, the UI pattern you are seeking is rather stale. I won't be the least bit surprised to see Google give `PreferenceActivity` a facelift in a future version of Android. You might wish to peruse [the "App Structure" page in the design guidelines](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/app-structure.html) for some other ideas.

Comment: What better structure do you propose for a directory-type navigation?

Comment: @baruch: If it is literally file directories, what you propose is probably your best available option, at least for smaller screen sizes.

Comment: Wouldn't replacing the ArrayAdapter for each level be better than relaunching as a new activity for each level? What are the advantages of your approach?

Comment: @baruch: "Wouldn't replacing the ArrayAdapter for each level be better than relaunching as a new activity for each level?" -- usually, we want animated effects on the menu level transitions, which are supplied automatically by launching activities or fragments. Using activities or fragments also handles the back stack for you.